# Error When Instantiating a Site Template in SharePoint 2010: "The site template requires that the feature {068bc832-4951-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66}..."

Tags: site-template, feature

I gave a talk at the most recent BASPUG meeting about developing in the Middle Tier. I used a SharePoint 2010 site for the demos and would like to make it available to the folks who are interested in it. I've saved the site as a template in my VM (Farm 1) and added it to the Solution Gallery on another farm (Farm 2) to make sure that I can instantiate it before making it available. Both farms are SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.

When I try to instantiate the template on Farm 2, I get this error:
"The site template requires that the feature {068bc832-4951-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66} be activated in the site collection."

The GUID {068bc832-4951-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66} represents the "Enhanced Theming" feature, based on Binging about. However, this feature must be a part of some other deployed feature bacause it isn't visible in Farm 1 or Farm 2.

I tried deactivating both the "SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features"  and "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features" in Farm 1 (even though they are active in Farm 2) just to give something a try, but no joy.

Both farms are fairly vanilla, but I can't swear that nothing's been activated/deactivated in Farm 2.

Any ideas? I suppose it could simply be a Farm 2 issue, too. Anyone want to try to instantiate the template? http://www.sympraxisconsulting.com/Demos/Demo%20Site%20Templates/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
Since I want to offer this for general use, I want to avoid a prerequisite like "Now run Powershell to..."

--UPDATE dateTime="2010-12-15 09:57:00 EST"--
Based on suggestions from @webdes03 and @petervandenberg, I activated the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" on Farm 2, which got me past the {068bc832-4951-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66} error and on to {063c26fa-3ccc-4180-8a84-b6f98e991df3}, which is "Library and Folder Based Retention". However, the mystery remains because Farm 1 *doesn't* have "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" activated.
--UPDATE--

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey Marc,
I reproduced the error. It's because of the Blank Site definition you have used as a top level site collection. Default it will not activate all features (like the theming one, but also it will cause problems for the Term Store Manager to appear). My advise for the future, don't use the Blank Team site as top level site collection as your first site on a webapplication. It works on the other site definitions. So I think you can spread this .wsp around with the instructions to NOT use it on the Blank Site but on every other like the Publishing or the Team site it will work....

-Peter

Comment: Excellent, Peter. I think that's the right explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Opened fine on my dev VM (eventually, the thing's running like a dog today).

Created it under a bog standard team site (on a vanilla SharePoint Server 2010 web app), everything loaded fine with no errors.

Comment: Well, that's a comfort. And now you have a bunch of stuff to look at that you didn't know you wanted. ;+)

Comment: Well, at least it's some awesome examples to keep for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

I have greenfield multi-server farm running in Hyper-V running SPS Enterprise.

I get error:

The site template requires that the Feature {14aafd3a-fcb9-4bb7-9ad7-d8e36b663bbd} be activated  in the site collection.

I look here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mcsnoiwb/features-and-their-guids-in-sp2010)

And it says

LocalSiteDirectoryControl
SharePoint Portal Server Local Site Directory Capture Control
14aafd3a-fcb9-4bb7-9ad7-d8e36b663bbd
Site

The status of the local site directory is kind of confusing in 2010, no?

JK